# How can i increment value Amount when an value is typed and button deposit is clicked?

Tags: c#, button, xamarin.forms

I can type the amount how much i want to deposit and when clicked deposit the value of Amount should increment for how much is typed. How to increment value of Amount which should be 0 at the beginning.(And later i want Amount to use to show as balance in other page).

I am working on a C# cross-platform app.

//MainPage.xaml

```
     <Label x:Name="Balance0"
           Text="Amount"
           FontSize="Large"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Editor Keyboard="Numeric"  />
    <Button Text="Deposit"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Command="{Binding DepositCommand}"/>
```

//ApiServices.cs

```
    public void Deposit(int Increment)
    {
        int Amount = 0;
        Amount += Increment;
    }
```

//DepositViewModel.cs

```
class DepositViewModel
{
    ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();

    public int Increment { get; set; }
    public ICommand Deposit
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                 _apiServices.Deposit(Increment);
            });
        }}}
```

Comment: Why not use an `Entry` here? Isn't an `Editor` a multi line control?

Answer (score 0):

you need to give your Editor control a name, or use databinding

```
// assume editor is named editDeposit, and contains an int value
// if the input is not a valid int, this will throw an exception
int deposit = Int.Parse(editDeposit.Text);

// increment the Amount
Amount += deposit;
```